# Deploying with Rubber to running EC2 instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2

I have googled but could not find a guide to deploying Rails app to a running EC2 instance with Rubber.

Can someone point out to the guide / or provide some instructions / key features from config files?

Comment: any luck on deploying into existing instance ?

Answer (score 0):

Try Railscasts. It has an episode on [Rubber](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=rubber).

Comment: yeah, but it suggests creating an instance. I want to deploy to the instance that I have already created..

Answer (score -1):

http://www.ginzametrics.com/deploy-rails-app-to-ec2-with-rubber.html

http://ramenlab.wordpress.com/2011/06/24/deploying-your-rails-app-to-aws-ec2-using-rubber/

Comment: it's all for creating an instance during deployment. I want to deploy to an existing instance.